# 英単語のアルファベットの間に半角スペースをいれたい。

Tags: 正規表現

インデザインCC15を使用しています。
英単語の一つ一つのアルファベット間に半角スペースを挿入させたいのですが、検索して一括置換させるような事は正規表現でできるのでしょうか？
例えば『Mon』→『M o n』のようにしたいです。
単語の前後には半角スペースを入れたくはありません。
×『 M o n 』     ○『M o n』
その行には英単語一語のみです。

詳しいかたがいれば教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: perl でしたら positive lookahead(肯定的先読み)を使って `([[:alpha:]])(?=[[:alpha:]])` としますが（変換は `s/([[:alpha:]])(?=[[:alpha:]])/\1 /g` ）、インデザインCC15で先読み・後読みなどをサポートしているのかどうか…？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

検索対象を`([A-Za-z])(?=[A-Za-z])`
置換対象を`\1`（\1の後ろに半角スペース一個です）

ではいかがでしょうか？

Comment: 承認下さりありがとうございます。しかし、正規表現の問題としては正解かも知れませんが、単語での検索が出来なくなるなど、デメリットの方が多いので、@sayuriさんの回答の様に、カーニングで解決する方がよい事象かとおもいます。

Answer (score 6):

本当に「半角スペースをいれたい」のでしょうか？

[文字の間隔を読みやすく調整する](https://helpx.adobe.com/jp/indesign/how-to/adjust-letter-spacing.html)で説明されているように字送りを調整するべきではないのでしょうか？